# What's the difference of special register and operator in informix?

Tags: database, informix

I am confused about the terms special register and operator in the database informix.

Can someone tell me the difference between these terms?

Comment: Can you identify where in the Informix manuals the term 'special register' is used?  That is a term that comes from DB2 primarily, AFAIK, and isn't generally associated with Informix at all.  Operators are used in expressions in SQL statements — there are a lot of operators with special symbolic spellings (logical operators such as AND, arithmetic operators such as `+` and `/`, and you can argue that functions are a form of operator).  With Informix, there can also be user-defined functions and aggregates and so on.

Comment: 1. CURRENT (Operator) -> See: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=expressions-current-operator 2. CURRENT TIMESTAMP (special register) -> See https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=registers-current-timestamp

Comment: I just realize that I have the two terms operator and special register from two different databases. The term operator is from Informix and the term special register is from DB2. Thank you Jonathan Leffler for your help.